# Why is system.io.Streamwriter getting skipped in my project?

Tags: vb.net

I am using a streamwriter to write inputted data into a csv file for a project but whenever i run through the debug stop it shows me that the code is skipping the writer for some reason.

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        Dim name As String = InputBox("Name of instrument")
        Dim cost As Integer = InputBox("Cost of instrument")
        Dim type As String = InputBox("Type of instrument")
        Dim wear As String = InputBox("Wear of instrument")
        Dim availability As String = InputBox("Availability of instrument")

        writeToFile("Instruments3.csv", arrInstruments.Length, name, cost, type, wear, availability, ",")
    End Sub

Function writeToFile(ByVal filepath As String, ByVal ID As Integer, ByVal name As String, ByVal cost As Integer, ByVal type As String, ByVal wear As String, ByVal availability As String, ByVal delimiter As String) As Boolean
        Try
            Dim fileWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(filepath, True)

            Dim record As String = ID + delimiter + name + delimiter + cost + delimiter + type + delimiter + wear + delimiter + availability

            fileWriter.WriteLine(record)
            fileWriter.Close()

            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("fail")

        End Try
    End Function
```

I attempted removing the Try-Catch statement but it just ran into an error where it was trying to convert the "," into double, idk why.

Comment: What EXACTLY does "skipping the writer" mean? It sounds like an exception was thrown so you need to explain that in detail. Vague descriptions are not enough. You need to specify exactly what line the exception is thrown on and what the error message is. Depending on the exception, specifying what data is being used on that line may be critical too.

Comment: The issue is probably the fact that you are using addition operators (`+`) to perform string concatenation. If you want to perform string concatenation then use concatenation operators (`&`). If you perform addition with a string and a number then the system will try to convert the string to a number, which is what is failing. If you perform concatenation then it will convert the number to a string, which is what you actually want. You should also have `Option Strict On` in your project properties, which probably would have flagged this as an issue.

Comment: I would also suggest that you call `String.Format` or use string interpolation any time you need to concatenate more than two substrings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```vb
Dim record As String = ID + delimiter + name + delimiter + cost + delimiter + type + delimiter + wear + delimiter + availability
```

should at least be this:

```vb
Dim record As String = ID & delimiter & name & delimiter & cost & delimiter & type & delimiter & wear & delimiter & availability
```

If you want to concatenate then use concatenation operators, not addition operators. Addition maps to concatenation for two strings but you're assuming that it does for a number and a string too, but it doesn't. Instead, the system will convert the string to a number and mathematically add them. If the string can't be converted to a number then you get the exception that you're seeing.

If you're going to concatenate more than two substrings though, you ought to use some other option. You can use string interpolation in newer versions of VB, plus you have the `Concat`, `Join` and `Format` methopds of the `String` class. In this specific case, `String.Join` is the most correct option, because it's purpose is to join multiple substrings with delimiters:

```vb
Dim record = String.Join(delimiter, {ID, name, cost, type, wear, availability})
```

I think that will work as is, but you may need to specify an `Object` array, given that the values are not all the same type:

```vb
Dim record = String.Join(delimiter, New Object() {ID, name, cost, type, wear, availability})
```